# How to insert a new row into table that its primary key is composite?

Tags: clojure, cassandra, hector

I created this table with cqsql --cql3 shell:

```
CREATE TABLE Stats (
 gsd          blob,
 period       int,
 tid          blob,
 sum          int,
 uniques      blob,
PRIMARY KEY(gid, period, tid)
);
```

I'm using [clj-hector](https://github.com/pingles/clj-hector) wrapper library.

I created the cluster and keyspace objects:

```
(def clstr (h/cluster "Test Cluster" "localhost"))

(def ksp (h/keyspace clstr "mks"))
```

How to insert a new row considering the previous structure? If you aren't familiar with clj-hector, Hector's code works for sure and I will morph it to Clojure.

Answer (score 1):

I believe, but have not verified, that you want to insert two columns:

row key is the value of gsd

One column has a composite name with value of period, value of tid and literal "sum" with a column value of sum

The second column has a composite name with value of period, value of tid, and literal "uniques" with a column value of uniques

Answer (score 0):

gid, period, tid are represented as "normal" columns from cql queries.

But you are probably better off using datastax/java-driver or one of it's clojure wrapper, hector is based on thrift, and it only has partial support for cql3 so I am not sure if that would even work.

shameless plug: have a look at https://github.com/mpenet/alia and https://github.com/mpenet/hayt

Answer (score 0):

You can refer to http://clojurecassandra.info/articles/kv.html this is a (rather generic) guide for CQL operations for people who use Cassandra with Clojure. You can use simple CQL syntax, the rest is handled by C* internally:

`INSERT INTO users (gsd, period, tid, sum, uniques) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?);`

For blobs, I would highly recommend using Prepared Statements, actually: http://clojurecassandra.info/articles/kv.html#toc_4

If you want to, you can checkout Cassaforte: https://github.com/clojurewerkz/cassaforte 
It's very easy to get up and running with it.